# Downgrading from 21.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, 21.04

By mistake I have upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.04. Is there an easy way of going back to the previous release?

Comment: why do you consider it a mistake? How was the upgrade done? please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Downgrading in Linux requires that you downgrade all the installed packages manually. It is almost impossible since there are many hundred of packages being upgraded and there is no automatic way to revert these upgrades.

Comment: 21.04 is very good, you may want to stick with it. Drawback is that you will need to upgrade again in december.

Comment: With this upgrade I could no longer share the screen in Zoom and was starting a meeting... Switching to Xorg seems to have solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Roll back is really based on your backup strategy so we can't help you there unless you tell us what strategy you put in place. As already stated there are no automatic tools to downgrade; and even if there were; they'd not go back to 20.04/focal, as the upgrade path from 20.10 was tested to 21.04; the upgrade path from 20.04 is to 20.10 OR in the future to the next LTS (ie. 22.04 after 22.04.1's release) so you've described an upgrade outside of intended upgrade paths & QA-testing (automated testing only is performed on unintended paths).  Stick to intended upgrade paths for best results.